# Photoshop on 4K monitor pixel count is off

Tags: windows-10, adobe-photoshop, pixels

I have a 4K monitor on Windows 10 with a custom display of `text,apps and other items 150%`.

[image]

When I take a screen grab and get the exact pixel size in Photoshop the pixel size is off.

You can see below that Photoshop is seeing a 300 x 300 square but in the html code I have set the image to be a 200 x 200 square.

How can I re calibrate Photoshop for the difference?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    div{
    width:200px; height:200px; display:block; background-color:pink;

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.  If I understand right, you're creating a 200x200 px square and then displaying it at 150%.  So what's written to the screen will be 300x300 px.  If you capture the screen, you capture the 300x300 box.  So that's what Photoshop sees when you examine it there.  You could resize the image in Photoshop, but there's nothing to calibrate.  If you want to capture the original size image in a screen grab, set the screen at 100% before you do the screen grab.

Comment: @fixer1234 If i set the screen at 100% everything is way too small because the screen hi res 4K.  I guess what I am asking is while keeping the 150% UI is there a way in photoshop to compensate.

Comment: A screen grab captures whatever is on the screen.  So you can temporarily change the screen magnification just for the screen grab, or grab the screen as-is and then resize in Photoshop back to the unmagnified size.  If you have to do that a lot, you could do batch resizing on a collection of screen image files before you open them, or maybe set up a shortcut key in Photoshop to resize with one click.

Comment: @fixer1234 yes that would work.  Just wondering if there was a more permanent fix in photoshop or Windows 10.